# Can we do case insensitive comparison in nxbre's if element

Tags: case-insensitive, nxbre

I am using NxBre 3.2.0. I want to compare two strings in case insensitive manner but did not find any option in IF element. Is it possible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you're using the Flow Engine since you mentionned `If`.

To perform a case insensitive comparison use the `ObjectLookup` element to call statically `String.Compare(left,right,true)`, then test the result to be equal to `0`.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks David for your quick reply. What I was looking for if there is any in-built way of doing so. However, I have resolved my problem as suggested by you. Thanks.